# Using non-CSS constants in GWT UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to use constants or defines in GWT's UiBinder XML. All the questions and answers I find are related to CSS constants, using @def annotations in a  elements, but that's not what I need. Take this example:

```
<g:Button width="60" height="24">Hello</g:Button>
```

If I have 50 buttons on my page, all with the same dimensions, I don't want to have to set each button's dimension as indicated above. If I want to change the width, I have to do this for all buttons on the page. So, what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
<g:Button width="{myWidth}" height="{myHeight}">Hello</g:Button>
```

The constants "myWidth" and "myHeight" being specified somewhere at the beginning of the UiBinder XML file. I tried doing this with  and  but I cannot get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A. This is how you do it:

```
<ui:with field="styleConstants" type="...constants.StyleConstants" />

<g:Button width="{styleConstants.myWidth}" height="{styleConstants.myHeight}">Hello</g:Button>
```

Obviously, StyleConstants should have myWidth() and myHeight() methods.

B. Setting the same size to 50 buttons is wrong. This is what CSS classes are for. Define a CSS class and assign it to each button:

```
<g:Button styleName="button">Hello</g:Button>
```

You can use an external CSS file or a CSS Resource for this purpose.

Comment: And `StyleConstants` could extend `com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.Constants` for instance.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: I am curious. What would be the benefit of existing `com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.Constants` ?

Comment: @Ümit: I18N; if you need something slightly wider/narrower in some locale because you know the text won't display correctly (German is known to generally have longer labels than, say, English). That and/or specifying your constant values in a properties file.